# Optimize MySQL Query using indexes (what index?)

Tags: mysql, performance

I am struggling to optimize the following query which takes an average of 2000 ms.

```
select  count(pk)
    from  mytable
    where  (pk<>5
      and  url='test.png'
      and  (data=124578 or  (data is null and  pk=1234578)))
      and  type in (123,456,789,015,789)
```

Here are some info :

```
select count(*) from mytable
```

1 526 588 lines

```
show indexes in mytable

Table   non_unique  key_name            seq_in_index    column_name collation   cardinality
mytable 0           PRIMARY             1               PK          A           1405079     
mytable 1           data                1               data        A           1405079     
mytable 1           Media_Code_30       1               code        A           1405079     
mytable 1           codeVersionIDX_30   1               code        A           1405079
```

Explain :

```
id  select_type table   type        possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    extra
1   SIMPLE      mytable ref_or_null PRIMARY,data    data    9       const   635908  Using where
```

I really have no idea whether this is optimized enough, or it can be better by creating new indexes (or composite indexes).

The query, however, cannot be changed as it is coming from another system on which I do not have my hands on!

Comment: Assuming `pk` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, hence never `NULL`, there is no need for `COUNT(pk)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, this query seems difficult to set up an index for:

```
select count(pk)
from mytable
where (pk <> 5 and url = 'test.png' and
       (data = 124578 or (data is null and pk = 1234578))
      ) and
      type in (123, 456, 789, 015, 789);
```

My suggestion is to start with `type` and include the other columns in the index:  `mytable(type, url, data, pk)`.  This is a covering index and that might improve performance a bit.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the Answer. Only some sample for using index

**SAMPLE**

**small Table**

```
MariaDB [bb]> SHOW CREATE TABLE useindex\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: useindex
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `useindex` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `num1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2031586 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**number of rows and sample data**

```
MariaDB [bb]> SELECT count(*) FROM USEindex;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  2000000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.43 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> SELECT * FROM useindex LIMIT 10;
+----+------+------+
| id | num1 | num2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |  405 |  906 |
|  2 |  656 |  656 |
|  3 |  906 |  407 |
|  4 |  156 |  157 |
|  5 |  406 |  908 |
|  6 |  656 |  659 |
|  7 |  907 |  409 |
|  8 |  157 |  160 |
|  9 |  407 |  910 |
| 10 |  657 |  661 |
+----+------+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EXPLAIN 3 queries (no index)**

```
MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM useindex WHERE num1 = 500;
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | useindex | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1996444 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM useindex WHERE num2 = 600;
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | useindex | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1996444 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM useindex WHERE num1 = 500 AND num2 = 600;
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | useindex | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1996444 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**add 2 indexe**

```
MariaDB [bb]> ALTER TABLE useindex
    -> ADD KEY n1 (num1),
    -> ADD KEY n2 (num2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (12.08 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**EXPLAIN with index**

see if the WHERE with 2 fields, MySQL use only one INDEX

```
MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM useindex WHERE num1 = 500;
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | useindex | ref  | n1            | n1   | 5       | const | 2003 |       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM useindex WHERE num2 = 600;
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | useindex | ref  | n2            | n2   | 5       | const | 1993 |       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM useindex WHERE num1 = 500 AND num2 = 600;
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | useindex | ref  | n1,n2         | n2   | 5       | const | 1993 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**add COMPOSITE Index over both fields**

```
MariaDB [bb]> ALTER TABLE useindex
    -> ADD KEY n12 (num1,num2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (7.83 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**EXPLAIN Queries again**

Now they use the COMOSITE Index

```
MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM useindex WHERE num1 = 500;
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | useindex | ref  | n1,n12        | n12  | 5       | const | 2003 | Using index |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM useindex WHERE num2 = 600;
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | useindex | ref  | n2            | n2   | 5       | const | 1993 |       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM useindex WHERE num1 = 500 AND num2 = 600;
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | useindex | ref  | n1,n2,n12     | n12  | 10      | const,const |    1 | Using index |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Tell the OPTIMIZER to MERGE INDEX**

```
MariaDB [bb]> SET optimizer_switch='index_merge=on';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

**drop INDEX n12**

```
MariaDB [bb]> alter table useindex drop key n12;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**RUN one QUERY with MERGE**

```
MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM useindex WHERE num1 = 500 AND num2 = 600;
+------+-------------+----------+-------------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type        | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                            |
+------+-------------+----------+-------------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | useindex | index_merge | n1,n2         | n2,n1 | 5,5     | NULL |    1 | Using intersect(n2,n1); Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+----------+-------------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]>
```

Comment: If MySQL uses only one index ever, how come that your final query shows that it merged information from multiple indexes in order to find required row?

Comment: YES, they MERGE!! 2 indexe, not use 2

Comment: But it **uses** two indexes to come up with the best path to retrieve the data, it's not like it used only one or another but both. You wrote that it only uses one index ever, and this snippet proves that it uses multiple indexes by merging them, since there's no other conceptual way to do it anyway. Therefore, MySQL is able to use multiple indexes per query. If MySQL only used one index per query, what would be the point of using MySQL if it's so poor with retrieval strategy (and we know it isn't poor with retrieval strategy)?

Comment: Yes, "index merge" will _sometimes_ use two indexes.  But it is almost always not as efficient as a 'composite index'.  [_More on composite indexes_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1).

Comment: Upvote for nice explanation and demo of various things.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can only use one INDEX in a query.

so it is necessary  to have composite index. the best way for the order of the fields in the index is the field which reduce the resultset mostly and so on.

lets say you have a table with names and birthday and you have many duplicates of names and only a few of birthday. so then create the index like (birthday,name) the mysql search first the records with the searched day and then only in this little result the name

Comment: Since when can MySQL use only one index in a query? Any docs to back that up? I'd like to believe you.

Comment: always, 20 years, i am not talking about subqueries. take a query a show what EPLAIN says. The OPTIMIZER looks for available Indexes und use the best one or none, or update me

Comment: So there's no document that states "MySQL uses only one index per query" or did I misunderstood you while you meant "In the query that OP posted, MySQL can use only one index"?

Comment: sorry, i can quick find a document with this information, but i also not found that mysql can use more. but i will search later gain and post you a link

Comment: Wouldn't it be kind of silly from MySQL developers to let you define multiple indexes if only one would be used every time? The only case that I can think of where MySQL chooses the best index is when multiple indexes overlap and it chooses the one that yields the best performance (for example querying using primary key and another column - primary key is sufficient to reduce the data set to a single record). I just don't think that your statement is entirely true, because if it were - why use MySQL if it's so poor with choosing indexes?

Comment: @Mjh - i have add a sample

Comment: I think "index merge" was added in version 5.0 (in 2003).  But I have almost never seen it in use.  (I have looked a lot of `EXPLAINs`.)

Comment: @Mjh - It is 'silly' for developers to "index every column", which I see from a lot of novices.  But it is certainly useful to have `INDEX(num1), INDEX(num2)` when you sometimes say `WHERE num1=123` and sometimes say `WHERE num2 = 123`.

Comment: @RickJames I don't understand your comment honestly, I was referring to people who are developing actual MySQL, not developers *using* it.

Comment: @Mjh - MySQL started out very lean and "good enough".  Using only one index was easy for the _developers_ to implement; using two indexes was a lot more complex.  (And the _users_ could work around it by using composite indexes, which is usually better anyway.)

Comment: "Index merge", subqueries, `VIEWs`, `PARTITIONing`, etc, are relative new features.  They give the user the illusion of better performance.  But in reality, they often don't help and sometimes hurt.

Comment: @RickJames - I'm sorry but I don't see how anything you wrote relates to this statement that MySQL can use only one index. The historic reflection you wrote has nothing to do with how state of the matter is today. Views, partitioning etc. has been added ages ago, it's not year 2005. but some people still behave as if it is. MySQL's able to use multiple indexes unless you have an explicit in-code proof that it does not. If it does not, I was wrong and I'll gladly admit my mistake. If I was right, then some misinformation was spread and I think we can all agree that false info is dangerous.

Comment: Actually using two indexes is so rare as to be not worth considering.  The only way that MySQL uses two indexes for a single `SELECT` involves fetching ids from each of two indexes, then 'anding' ('intersect') or 'oring' ('union') the lists in some temp space.  All of this is bulky and slow, hence rarely improves performance over simply using one index, then filtering on the `WHERE` or (in the case of `JOIN`, using Nested Loop Join).

Comment: I captured a rare example of using two indexes, and how a composite index probably out-performs it, in one of [my blogs](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1).

Comment: One of my points is that the MySQL optimizer will often choose to use just one index, even if it could use two.  And it is usually "right" to eschew the two-index approach.

Comment: Perhaps a difference between MySQL and, say, Oracle, is the absence of dependence on a "rownum".  InnoDB has the `PRIMARY KEY`, instead, and that is perhaps more costly to use than a rownum.  Hence, Oracle _may_ correctly choose to use two indexes in a case where MySQL would correctly choose not to.

Comment: I'm somewhere in the middle ground between Bernd's "can't use multiple indexes" (which is _wrong_) and Mjh's "ought to use multiple indexes".

Answer (score 0):

The best index for that query is

```
INDEX(url, type) -- in that order
```

Indexes should start with any columns that are "= constant" (`url` in this case), then move on to one more column that is more complex (`type IN ...`).  [*See my cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).